# php защита продукта, удаленный include

Tags: php

Сделал небольшой скрипт, хочу его продавать но так чтобы не могли украсть код. Можно ли подгружать код с удаленного сервера? Чтобы его мог прочитать только php скрипт и всё. Или какие есть еще способы защиты от воровства и исправления кода?

Comment: Попробуйте продавать не продукт, а услугу.

Comment: Можете добавить описание и лицензию к своему коду, но никому не помешаете нарушить эту лицензию.

Answer (score 4):

Нет, таким образом защитить ничего нельзя.

Можно сделать API, которое принимает JSON с запросом и возвращает JSON с результатом.

Comment: После чего, вполне себе неплохо жить, взимая с  клиентов плату за использование этого самого API ) Клиентскую часть вообще сделать опенсорс, да  предоставлять всем пользователям небольшое количество бесплатных обращений - соблазнения потенциальных клиентов ради ))

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать ioncube http://www.ioncube.com/ для шифрование файлов по ключу. подробнее документация по ссылке выше.

Comment: Правда это не особо помешает его расшифровать, если прям-прям захочется ) Декодеров куча.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov Попробуйте расшифровать )) это не такая уж и лёгкая задача.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov вам как минимум нужно два ключа NEW SECURITY FEATURES of JIT decoding plus External and innovative Algorithmic Dynamic keys. у вас только один на компе. да и это Binary code obfuscation. т.е. вы сможете выстановить алгоритм, а это тоже што и написать самому.

Answer (score 0):

Начните с осознания того, ЗАЧЕМ вам защищать код. 
Если речь идёт про действительно маленький удобный скрипт который стоит малых денег и просто не хочется чтобы его кто-то брал нахаляву - есть смысл использовать качественные готовые решения, потому что взлом готовых систем защиты просто так на дороге не валяется и точно будет стоить дороже чем простая покупка скрипта у вас.
Если код претендует на что-то серьёзное, что будет выгодно для злоумышленника взломать с вложением средств и усилий и потом продавать - тогда уже может быть смысл в изобретении собственного метода защиты, но при этом стоит помнить что он может и не оказаться более надёжным, чем готовое решение от профессионалов. 
Если скрипт действительно небольшой и узкоспециализированный,а деньги за него не планируете брать какие-то невероятные - не стоит изобретать велосипед.